# scheduling Android notification on a specific date

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm try to schedule a notification for a certain date:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION,
            notification);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long delay = millisFromNow(date);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, delay,
            pendingIntent);
```

But notification appear some second after i've schedule it.
This is hoi i calculate mills for a future date:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
try {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return -1;
}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` read the doc for that.

Comment: also, `long delay = millisFromNow(date);` is probably the amount of time from now to the alarm you want to trigger? again, read the documentation for `alarmManager.set` as it does not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this flag to set the notification alarm:

```
AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
```

as the documentation says: 
Alarm time in `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` (***time since boot***, including sleep), which will wake up the device when it goes off.

So  this flag is used to trigger the alarm since boot time, I'd recommend you to change to:

```
AlarmManager.RTC
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, i've pasted wrong flag. Also with AlarmManager.RTC flag notification doesn't start at prefixed time. I've noticed also that my function for get millis return a negative value...